# exposition on arrows in haskell

Tags: haskell, arrows

What would be a good place to go to understand arrows? Ideally, I am just looking for some place with a concise definition with motivation from some good examples, something similar to Wadler's exposition on monads.

Comment: It would be useful if you could make the question title a little clearer.  Perhaps, "Exposition on Arrows in Haskell"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found Hughes' original paper ("Generalizing Monads to Arrows") to be fairly accessible.  You can read an older draft of it [here](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/arrows.pdf).  It has some differences from the original paper, which are noted on the [bibliography page](http://www.haskell.org/arrows/biblio.html) of Ross Patterson's own [overview of Arrows](http://www.haskell.org/arrows/index.html).

Answer (score 7):

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows

Answer (score 2):

If you learn better from practice than theory, try using [HXT](http://www.fh-wedel.de/~si/HXmlToolbox/) for XML manipulation, or [PArrows](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ekarttun/PArrows/) for general parsing.  They both have APIs centered around arrows.

Comment: Where did the *PArrows* site go?

Comment: @Dario http://hackage.haskell.org/package/PArrows seems to be the only source now, without maintainer.  :-(